# No suitable default RequestUpgradeStrategy found on Dailyrazor's tomcat 8.5 server

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket

I am fairly new to spring-boot and Websockets in general. I am attempting to create a program that requires websockets to manage a chat application. The program runs perfectly fine on my local machine. However, when uploading it to my tomcat server on Dailyrazor, I get the error message `No suitable default RequestUpgradeStrategy found`.

What I have tried:

1. I have checked my spring-boot version to ensure that it is compatible with my Tomcat 8.5 server
2. I have checked to make sure that my websockets version is also compatible. It is also important to note that my program ran perfectly fine on Dailyrazor before I added websockets to it.

Here is my build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.2.2.RELEASE"
        classpath "io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:1.0.8.RELEASE"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'war'
}

group 'com.teamtreehouse'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'



allprojects  {
    apply plugin: 'maven'
    apply plugin: "io.spring.dependency-management"
    group = 'com.wnp'
    version = '6.5.0-SNAPSHOT'
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: "org.springframework.boot"

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-websocket

//    compile 'org.projectreactor:reactor-spring:1.0.1.release'
    implementation 'io.spring.dependency-management:io.spring.dependency-management.gradle.plugin:1.1.0'

    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
//// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web
//    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-web:6.0.0'


    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail:2.2.2.RELEASE'

    compile group: 'org.apache.maven.plugins', name: 'maven-surefire-plugin', version: '2.22.2'
    implementation 'org.ocpsoft.prettytime:prettytime:3.2.7.Final'

//    compile 'org.springframework:spring-orm'
//    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat
//    providedRuntime group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat', version: '2.7.5'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat
    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:2.2.2.RELEASE'

    compile 'org.eclipse.mylyn.github:org.eclipse.egit.github.core:2.1.5'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    compile 'org.hashids:hashids:1.0.1'

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java
    implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.33'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket'

    testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    implementation group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk-s3', version: '1.12.131'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.28'

    testImplementation 'software.amazon.awssdk:s3:2.17.102'

    runtimeOnly 'software.amazon.awssdk:bom:2.17.102'


}
```

Here is my websockets configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/chat");
        registry.addEndpoint("/chat").withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    }


}
```

Finally, here is my error log:

```
INFO next-step-co.com-startStop-2 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[next-step-co.com].[/] - 2 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
INFO mysql-cj-abandoned-connection-cleanup org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader - Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load .  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
INFO next-step-co.com-startStop-2 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[next-step-co.com].[/] - Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
ERROR next-step-co.com-startStop-2 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase - ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[next-step-co.com].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:919)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1704)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'stompWebSocketHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/socket/config/annotation/DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'stompWebSocketHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No suitable default RequestUpgradeStrategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:656)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:484)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$878/444480024.getObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:152)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:132)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5164)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'stompWebSocketHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No suitable default RequestUpgradeStrategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No suitable default RequestUpgradeStrategy found
    at org.springframework.web.socket.server.support.AbstractHandshakeHandler.initRequestUpgradeStrategy(AbstractHandshakeHandler.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.server.support.AbstractHandshakeHandler.<init>(AbstractHandshakeHandler.java:119)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.server.support.DefaultHandshakeHandler.<init>(DefaultHandshakeHandler.java:35)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.server.support.WebSocketHttpRequestHandler.<init>(WebSocketHttpRequestHandler.java:74)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebMvcStompWebSocketEndpointRegistration.getMappings(WebMvcStompWebSocketEndpointRegistration.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebMvcStompEndpointRegistry.getHandlerMapping(WebMvcStompEndpointRegistry.java:155)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurationSupport.stompWebSocketHandlerMapping(WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurationSupport.java:82)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$89bc0503.CGLIB$stompWebSocketHandlerMapping$11(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$89bc0503$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d170f115.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$89bc0503.stompWebSocketHandlerMapping(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 34 more
ERROR next-step-co.com-startStop-2 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig - Error deploying web application archive /home/nextste2/tomcat/webapps/next-step-co.com/ROOT.war
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[next-step-co.com].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:919)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1704)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates that Spring is unable to upgrade the HTTP request to a WebSocket connection on your Tomcat server.

There are few things to check:

- Make sure you are using a compatible version of Tomcat that supports Servlet 3.1 or later. Tomcat 8.5 meets this requirement.
- Add the `tomcat-websocket` dependency to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
  <version>9.0.43</version> 
</dependency>
```

- Configure Spring to use the TomcatRequestUpgradeStrategy:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

  @Override
  public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/chat").setHandshakeHandler(new DefaultHandshakeHandler(
      new TomcatRequestUpgradeStrategy())).withSockJS();
  }

}
```

This explicitly configures Spring to use Tomcat's built-in WebSocket support.

Comment: I am using Spring starter-web which has a built in tomcat. Wouldn't adding another tomcat interfere with that?